# Firefox: can a shortcut be defined for a site specific Google search?

Tags: firefox, search, shortcuts

Is it possible to define shortcuts in Firefox to do a Google 
search restricted to a particular site?

Background: in the Opera web browser I can define a 
shortcut, say "su", to do a Google search restricted to a 
particular site, e.g. superuser.com. This shortcut can be 
used from the address bar.

Example:

su firewall

will do the same as opening www.google.com and typing:

site:superuser.com firewall

The definition for this is:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:superuser.com+%s&sourceid=opera&num=%i&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
```

where "%s" represent the search string - "firewall" in the 
example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and the exact same syntax is used in the Firefox bookmarks.  You may want to do a google search that you want with some replacement for the text you want to replace (I use XYZZY for this, it's easy to spot).   Then replace XYZZY with %s, and add a "keyword" to the bookmark (it's in the "more options" section of the bookmark manager).   Then you can type the keyword and whatever you put after the keyword will replace %s in the URL.

See [this reference](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/firefox/kws.htm) for keywords in Firefox.   I tend to leave the trailing colon out of my keywords, they're easier to type.  Lifehacker also had a [decent article](http://lifehacker.com/software/bookmarks/hack-attack-firefox-and-the-art-of-keyword-bookmarking-196779.php) on it which may be more recent.

Comment: Ah yes. I have tried it now and it works. Thanks!

Comment: It even works with delicious.com and the Delicious Toolbar (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615) if you're using that. Right-click in the search field and choose "Add a keyword for this search in Delicious", and you can use the shortcut everywhere you have the toolbar installed. I suppose you also can create the link manually on Delicious and tag it with shortcut:foo (where "foo" is the shortcut itself).